# Magento 2.1.1 Checkout page is blank after login

Tags: magento2

I tried to run Magento(CE) 2.1.1 in my server but it seems that my checkout page isn't displaying anything, just header and footer.

Comment: you should have some errors in the browser console. Can you check and provide more details about the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to enable the display error messages ?

here is how to do it :
rename local.xml.sample in local.xml in the folder pub/errors/
and be sure that in /bootstrap.php you have this two lined uncommented :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Please don't spam your website. That belongs in your profile not in your answers.

Comment: where is the bootstrap.php file located

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 826253 bytes) in /home/ourshop/public_html/migrate/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php on line 311 how to slove it